# What is a $0$-sublevel set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I read the notes of S. Boyd, and am confused about the following:

[image]

$f_0(x)$ is quasiconvex. I am confused about the latter one particularly.
What does it mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $0$-sublevel set of a function $g$ is the set $\{x: g(x)\le 0\}$.

Generally, the $t$-sublevel set of a function $g$ is the set $\{x: g(x)\le t\}$.

A function $g$ is called quasiconvex if for every $t$, the set $\{x: g(x)\le t\}$ is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set).

Comment: Could you please show an example where a quasi-convex function is not convex?